# Vim substitute till end of line in normal mode

Tags: vim

I have some text yanked using `yiw`. Now, on another line, I want to replace text from current cursor position until end of line, so I try `v$p`. However, this also deletes the newline at the end of the line which I don't want to happen. How do I address this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

- adjust the visual area before putting:

  ```
  v$hp
  ```
- use the `:help g_` motion if you don't have trailing space:

  ```
  vg_p
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You can delete into the null register and then paste with `"_Dp`

Alternatively, if you want to save the text you're deleting, you can delete in the normal buffer, and past from the 0 buffer with `D"0p`

I find register keys clunky, so I have maps in my .vimrc for them:

```
" leader means "another option key like cmd or meta, but one you get to choose"
let mapleader = "\<Space>"
" get the yank register, not the thing you just deleted
nnoremap <Leader>p "0p
nnoremap <Leader>P "0P
" don't copy the thing you're gonna delete into the delete register
nnoremap <Leader>d "_d
nnoremap <Leader>D "_D
```

With these binds, it becomes  `Dp` or `D p` depending on whether you want to keep the deleted text.

---

If you don't want to mess with registers at all, there's always the simple `PlD`.

Comment: PlD is awesomest (though not aesthetically nice). I didn't want to mess with registers but will probably have a go at what you described!